# Branding and logo

Tags: discussion, design

It's important to make the site very recognizable and have a distinctive look and feel. I imagine something following the design line of [`substrate.io`](https://substrate.io) should feel familiar to people making it look like both sites are part of the same developer experience. If Parity is behind that website I suppose taking care of the stackexchange site branding wouldn't be a problem.

Another option as the site includes Polkadot name is to leave it to the Polkadot community and its governance to decide how to brand the site although it seems like an overkill.

Comment: What is the specific suggestion here? You want to add custom CSS and favicon? Do you have specific suggestions for these?

Comment: Sure you could say that, but ideally something with a bit more thought than just throwing random "custom CSS and favicon", it shouldn't be just changing a color but a proper design based on the constraints we have for customization(also include fonts, icons, vote arrows, etc) and my suggestion here is that it can be a design put together by Parity since the company is behind the design of substrate.io which is a visual style that would fit the stackexchange site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sites do not get custom designs, logos and other decorative elements until they leave public beta - and even then we have a huge backlog. Right now y'all should be focused on making the site a great place to ask questions and get answers about Substrate and Polkadot - designs won't be coming any time soon.